# What are the screen sizes of my Android emulators in dp?

Tags: android

I have the following emulators on my Windows machine:

[image]

what are their sizes in dp?

For example, when I start my app on selected Nexus emulator, its `demens` are loaded from

```
values-sw720dp
```

but not from

```
values-sw1200dp
```

or

```
values-sw1600dp
```

So the question is, for example, what exact size of this emulator in dp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert dp units to pixel units:

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160) /* density */
```

Density qualifiers mapping:

```
ldpi      (~120dpi)
mdpi      (~160dpi)
hdpi      (~240dpi)
xhdpi     (~320dpi)
xxhdpi    (~480dpi)
xxxhdpi   (~640dpi)
```

With a `-sw[N]dp (smallestWidth)` modifier you are saying:

Use this resource on any device whose smallest dimension (screen's smallest dimension) is `[N]dp` or greater.

So, If you selected emulator with screen size `2560px x 1600px (xhdpi ~320dpi)` its `smallestWidth` will be:

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
dp = 1600 / (320 / 160) 
dp = 800
```

sw720dp < **800dp** < sw1200dp < sw1600dp

References: [AlternativeResources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), [ScreenDensities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities), [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)